# Error When Changing Constraints on an SKView

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit, ios-autolayout

I'm making a game where I have an SKView inside a UIView, and inside the SKView is an SKScene. In the `viewDidLoad()` method I want to change a constraint on the SKView, specifically the aspect ratio. I already have an aspect ratio of 1:1 applied to it, and I created a method to change the aspect ratio to the desired one. In my `viewDidLoad()` method, I call the following:

```
ratioConstraint = changeMultiplier(ratioConstraint, multiplier: 2)
```

where `ratioConstraint` is the constraint responsible for the aspect ratio, and `changeMultiplier` is the following:

```
func changeMultiplier(constraint: NSLayoutConstraint, multiplier: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint {

    let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: constraint.firstItem,
        attribute: constraint.firstAttribute,
        relatedBy: constraint.relation,
        toItem: constraint.secondItem,
        attribute: constraint.secondAttribute,
        multiplier: multiplier,
        constant: constraint.constant)

    newConstraint.priority = constraint.priority

    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints([constraint])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([newConstraint])

    return newConstraint

}
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
<CAEAGLLayer: 0x7fc4e0f12450>: calling -display has no effect.
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I created another test project where I mimic this behavior, and it works as expected. Any help would be great. If it would help, I can post the test project to show the behavior that I want. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: After further testing, I've discovered that this error only occurs when `changeMultiplier` is called in `viewDidLoad`, which is why it was working in my test project because I was calling it upon pressing a button. When should I call it to update the aspect ratio before presenting the view?

EDIT: Moving it to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` fixed the problem. However, now if I rotate the device, the SKView disappears, which did not happen before.

Comment: That should not be an error, that is just a warning that nothing is happening.  You should be changing your constraints during the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method

Comment: @Knight0fDragon When it gives me that warning, the SKView is not drawn. Also, I believe that I already tried it there.

Comment: not sure why you are trying to change the aspect ratio of the view,  unless you are only using part of the screen for sprite kit, this is not necessary

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I am only using part of the screen.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I was wrong - it was `viewWillLayoutSubviews` that I had tried. It worked in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as you suggested. However, know the SKView disappears if I rotate the device.

Comment: you need to fix your constraints based on the landscaping

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Do you know what specifically might be the problem?

Comment: no because I do not know your constraints,  Not even sure why you are multiplying an aspect ratio of 1:1, since it doesn't change the ratio

Comment: @Knight0fDragon If I comment out the line where I call changeMultiplier, the problem does not persist, even if I change the aspect ratio. Also, if instead I comment out `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([newConstraint])`, nothing is drawn before I even rotate. This makes me believe that there is a problem with either creating or activating `newConstraint`.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I don't know how, but I fixed my issue. I was playing around with some things to try to find the issue, and I must have changed something that fixed it. Thanks for the help